# SQL Query is only selecting 2 out of 4 records - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to select 4 fund names and their relating contacts. However, only two is being selected. I want to be able to select all 4 funds regardless if they have associated contact names.

Below is my SQL:

```
select mutual_Fund_name, concat(contact_first_name,' ',contact_last_name)  
from mutual_fund mf, contact c, mutual_fund_has_contact mfhc, institution i,  institution_has_mutual_Fund ihmf 
where mf.mutual_fund_id = mfhc.mutual_fund_id 
      and c.contact_id = mfhc.contact_id 
      and ihmf.mutual_fund_id = mf.mutual_fund_id 
      and i.institution_id = ihmf.institution_id 
      and mf.mutual_fund_name 
          in ('Vanguard Balanced Index Fund', 
              'Vanguard Consumer Discretionary Index Fund',
              'Vanguard Extended Market Index Fund', 
              'Vanguard Growth Index Fund') 
order by mutual_fund_name;
```

How do I get all funds with their contacts (regardless if the fund has any) to return in my sql statement?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is what you want

Comment: Thank you! that worked, only thing i had to change is to use left outer join

Comment: And if you would gladly put it as an answer, i would gladly up vote you and mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you would need explicit `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. This *should* be sufficient.

```
SELECT mutual_fund_name, CONCAT(contact_first_name,' ',contact_last_name)  
FROM mutual_fund mf
    LEFT JOIN mutual_fund_has_contact mfhc ON mf.mutual_fund_id = mfhc.mutual_fund_id
    LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.contact_id = mfhc.contact_id 
    LEFT JOIN institution i ON i.institution_id = ihmf.institution_id
    LEFT JOIN institution_has_mutual_Fund ihmf ON ihmf.mutual_fund_id = mf.mutual_fund_id
WHERE mf.mutual_fund_name IN ('Vanguard Balanced Index Fund', 
    'Vanguard Consumer Discretionary Index Fund',
    'Vanguard Extended Market Index Fund', 
    'Vanguard Growth Index Fund')
ORDER BY mutual_fund_name;
```

Comment: Yep, but the lower two left joins are not necessary and may just slow things down considerably, depending on how the query is optimized.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Assuming that the given `SELECT` statement is really all that's being used, yes. I was kind of going with the assumption that it is merely a simplified example.

Comment: If it's a simplified example, it's a simplified example. He can add the add the other joins later. :P

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviated join syntax (which you're using) only represents an `INNER JOIN`, which excludes items if there is no corresponding row in the other table. You need to use `LEFT JOIN` (and the more descriptive join syntax) to include all mutual funds, even if they don't have a corresponding contact name.

```
select
  mutual_Fund_name,
  concat(contact_first_name,' ',contact_last_name) as 'contact name' 
from mutual_fund mf
left join mutual_fund_has_contact mfhc on mf.mutual_fund_id = mfhc.mutual_fund_id
left join contact c on mfhc.contact_id = c.contact_id
left join institution_has_mutual_Fund ihmf on mf.mutual_fund_id = ihmf.mutual_fund_id
left join institution i on ihmf.institution_id = i.institution_id
where mf.mutual_fund_name in (
  'Vanguard Balanced Index Fund', 
  'Vanguard Consumer Discretionary Index Fund',
  'Vanguard Extended Market Index Fund', 
  'Vanguard Growth Index Fund'
) 
order by mutual_fund_name;
```

Also, some of the joins you have are actually not necessary for this query, so you can get away with:

```
select
  mutual_Fund_name,
  concat(contact_first_name,' ',contact_last_name) as 'contact name' 
from mutual_fund mf
left join mutual_fund_has_contact mfhc on mf.mutual_fund_id = mfhc.mutual_fund_id
left join contact c on mfhc.contact_id = c.contact_id
where mf.mutual_fund_name in (
  'Vanguard Balanced Index Fund', 
  'Vanguard Consumer Discretionary Index Fund',
  'Vanguard Extended Market Index Fund', 
  'Vanguard Growth Index Fund'
) 
order by mutual_fund_name;
```